# Arabic and English text in PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, pgadmin

I need to insert both English and Arabic text into a PostgreSQL database.

I'm running the following command via a .bat script:

```
psql.exe --echo-all --username=postgres --dbname=dbname -f populate.sql
```

`populate.sql` has statements like this:

```
insert into table1 (column1, column2) VALUES (2, 'المستخدم ');
```

If I do this via pgadmin, it works. The thing is I need to do this via some .sql population scripts that are ran once the application is started.

In that case I get gibberish, like this:

`Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¶`

I created the scripts in Notepad++ using the `Encode in UTF-8 without BOM` option, since the normal encoding in UTF-8 adds an extra character to the start of the file and some of the inserts are not made.

I'm assuming this is an encode problem, but I have yet to figure out exactly what is wrong. 
The databse is in UTF-8.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Windows console doesn't speak Unicode of any form by default, it speaks a "native" codepage. Which codepage depends on your Windows install's language settings.

If you `chcp 65001` then it'll switch into utf-8.

Overall, though, text encoding handling in batch/cmd files and the Windows command line is absolutely awful. I generally recommend that you instead put anything that isn't basically 7-bit ASCII into a separate .sql file and execute it via `psql -f` with a suitable `client_encoding`; the `PGCLIENTENCODING` environment variable is useful for this.

So try:

```
SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8
psql.exe --username=postgres --dbname=dbname -f populate.sql
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the `PGCLIENTENCODING` solves it!
The inserts are correctly made and no more gibberish!